# How to connect to SQL Server from a client machine?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hello everybody i have a question and confusion about a project that i developed, and I will be very happy if you help me to improve my project.

I worked in VS2010 with C# and my database is attached in Sql Server 2008. my app is supposed to work in a LAN, so i'm thinking to make two versions of this app, the first will include the database and the sql server(plus the winforms of course), the second will just contain dotNet framework and it's supposed to connect to the database installed on the other machine. Is it possible. If so, how??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it is posible.
alter your connection string's "data source" to "ip address of the server"

Suppose in your machine where sql server is installed you are using this connection string

```
"data source=localhost;initial catalog=databasename;uid=sa;pwd=password"
```

then in the client system you need to alter it like this

```
"data source=IpAddressOfTheServer;initial catalog=databasename;uid=sa;pwd=password"
```

Note: the application having server's ip address in connection string is accessible by both, server and the client.

Answer (score 0):

if Connection String  in your  (c# ) code  Setted, Change connection string's "Data Source" to "IP address of server"
an another way  change connection string  in  (App Config  or WebConfig) at  StartUp Project by below format:

```
 <configuration>  
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="DB" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.10.5;
    Initial Catalog=SafetyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;
    Password=a1234$; connection timeout=5000" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: In his windows application he just wants to connect to SQL Server through client machine. that's all.